Is there any way to get nulls last without calling order by?
Let's say we have a query as follows:

SELECT a, b, c  FROM my_table ORDER BY a nulls last

Is there a way to define a query to

SELECT a, b, c FROM my_table

with a column nulls last, without ordering?
Something on the line:

SELECT a, b, c  FROM my_table WHERE a nulls last

Basically, I would like to get the speed of a non sorted select, with some of the sorting features.

You could do two selects one after another with null conditions on the column.

When something has to come last, you have to order. Right?

well not necessarily. You may implement a sift approach with 2 buckets to collect the result, in the first one you collect the non null ones while in the second one you collect the null ones. and in the end you merge

@Yonoss you don't need any "buckets" and "merge". Just do two selects one after another. Why is that not a valid solution? If you put a smart index (two valued: "null" and "not null") it very likely to be as fast as single select without ordering.

@freakish I can do that but it won't be as fast as a single select, as my column value will be calculated on the fly (is actually a geodesic distance in between the user location and element location) so indexing that won't be feasible . And I'm really looking for performance here, on results sets that could potentially have millions of entries.

@Yonoss that's an important piece of information that you should include in the question. How big is the result set?

@freakish it can be anywhere from 0 to about 50 million and growing

Instead of ordering all content, you could order on just the null: ORDER BY a IS NULL;

This is not going to get a useful answer until you provide the actual query being used with EXPLAIN ANALYZE from it's use against actual data. Also the definition of the table involved.

@Adrian Klaver I can't provide my production query as it is a very complicated one and without providing the whole schema (which I won't) It won't make much sense. I am strictly looking for an answer to my question. Nothing else. Thanks for understanding this situation.

To answer the question asked:

Is there any way to get nulls last without calling order by?

UNION ALL comes to mind:
SELECT a, b, c FROM my_table
WHERE  a IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, c FROM my_table
WHERE  a IS NULL;

If one of both parts is relatively small, a partial index for the rare case would make it fast.
But see:

Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?

You may have to make sure the two parts don't get mixed.
The best solution depends on (undisclosed) details of your setup and requirements.

Thanks for the suggestion, but with this approach at times I'm seeing response times slower than what I am getting when ordering the result set. eg: response time for non ordered select: ~0.2 seconds; response time for ordered select ~ 4 to 8 seconds; response time for union all approach: up to 20 seconds;
